# Can't establish VPN with Mac Cisco

Tags: network, vpn

I am trying to connect to Universities VPN. I am using Cisco anyconnect.

That is the error I have:

```
The VPN connection is not allowed via a local proxy. This can be changed
through AnyConnect profile settings.
```

I have checked [Cisco troubleshooting](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100597-technote-anyconnect-00.html). And modified the file Remote.Access.xml.

```
    <ProxySettings>IgnoreProxy</ProxySettings>
```

Instead of:

```
    <ProxySettings>Native</ProxySettings>
```

When leaving the file after the mods I used `sudo chmod 444 Remote.Access.xml` to prevent changes, because each time I try to make a connection the file changes back to `<ProxySettings>Native</ProxySettings>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are having problems connecting with your University's VPN, have you approached the University's IT department for help?

Comment: @IconDaemonyes, sure. They say that everything must work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/639323/869866 - this is why profiles are overwritten